# Spring boot (Redis) LettuceConnectionFactory unable to recover if any node goes down from cluster

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, redis-sentinel, ioredis

I have 4 node cluster machine

1. 3 Replica of Redis
2. 3 Replica of Sentinel

Deleting Redis master node LettuceConnectionFactory throws the following error and does not recover from this state and stops all other Redis operations.

```
Cannot connect Redis Sentinel at RedisURI [host='sentinel', port=5000]: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: sentinel:5000
[2023-10-30 19:27:16,749] [ERROR] [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-2] [io.lettuce.core.masterslave.SentinelConnector.lambda$null$3 : 116]
    Error during background refresh

            io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to RedisURI [sentinels=[RedisURI [host='sentinel', port=5000]], sentinelMasterId=mymaster]
        
        Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Cannot connect Redis Sentinel at RedisURI [host='sentinel', port=5000]
            at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.lambda$connectSentinelAsync$9(RedisClient.java:555)
            at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorMap$28(Mono.java:3763)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94)
            ... 29 common frames omitted
    
    Caused by: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: sentinel:5000
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:261)
```

Following is my LettuceConnectionFactory connection

```
ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions topologyRefreshOptions = ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions.builder()
                .enablePeriodicRefresh(Duration.ofSeconds(1)) // Refresh the topology periodically.
                .enableAllAdaptiveRefreshTriggers() // Refresh the topology based on events.
                .build();

        ClusterClientOptions clusterClientOptions = ClusterClientOptions.builder()
                .timeoutOptions(TimeoutOptions.enabled(Duration.ofSeconds(15)))
                .topologyRefreshOptions(topologyRefreshOptions).build();

        RedisSentinelConfiguration sentinelConfig = new RedisSentinelConfiguration().master("mymaster");
        sentinelConfig.sentinel(host, Integer.parseInt(port));

        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(sentinelConfig, LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
                .clientOptions(clusterClientOptions).readFrom(ReadFrom.REPLICA_PREFERRED).build());
```

is there any parameter that i am missing?